# how to get the maximuim ID from two rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was doing a partition using ranking here is the query below

```
    SELECT RN = RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY PatID ORDER BY ChargeId DESC
        )
    ,chargeID
    ,patid
    ,transactiontype
    ,pOSTdATE
FROM [TransactionMasterReport]
WHERE patid = 598
    AND servicedate = '2017-05-17 00:00:00.0000000'
    AND cptcode = '96365'
    AND transactiontype != 'adjustments'
    AND transactiontype != 'payments'
    AND transactiontype = 'Charges'
GROUP BY chargeID
    ,patid
    ,transactiontype
    ,pOSTdATE
```

OutPut :[image: table1]

The Logic is Transactiontype='Charges'-TransactionType='Voided Charges'
But i need to keep the latest Charges if you see above chargeID is different for one row ,i need to retain that chargeId as my output.

Below is another query excuted **TransactionType !='Voided Charges'**

```
    SELECT RN = RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY PatID ORDER BY ChargeId DESC
        )
    ,chargeID
    ,patid
    ,transactiontype
    ,pOSTdATE
FROM [TransactionMasterReport]
WHERE patid = 598
    AND servicedate = '2017-05-17 00:00:00.0000000'
    AND cptcode = '96365'
    AND transactiontype != 'adjustments'
    AND transactiontype != 'payments'
    AND transactiontype != 'Voided Charges'
    AND transactiontype = 'Charges'
```

output:[image: output2]

from the output i need to keep the **maximuim chargeID**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY PatID ORDER BY ChargeId DESC
            ) [RN]
        ,chargeID
        ,patid
        ,transactiontype
        ,pOSTdATE
    FROM [TransactionMasterReport]
    WHERE patid = 598
        AND servicedate = '2017-05-17 00:00:00.0000000'
        AND cptcode = '96365'
        AND transactiontype != 'adjustments'
        AND transactiontype != 'payments'
        AND transactiontype = 'Charges'
    GROUP BY chargeID
        ,patid
        ,transactiontype
        ,pOSTdATE
    ) a
WHERE a.rn = 1
```

and you can adjust the where conditions within the sub query accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add to your where clause to select where the RN = 1

```
WITH cteRank AS
(select  RN = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY PatID order by ChargeId desc), 

chargeID,patid,transactiontype,pOSTdATE from [TransactionMasterReport] where 

patid=598 and servicedate = '2017-05-17 00:00:00.0000000' and cptcode ='96365' 

AND transactiontype !='adjustments' AND transactiontype !='payments'  and 

transactiontype !='Voided Charges' AND  transactiontype = 'Charges')
SELECT * 
FROM cteRank
WHERE RN = 1
```